# How to make crisp text in Textfield Label while zooming is enabled in scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

Hi I am working on app in which zooming is enable in scrollview and there are many text fields and labels in scrollview. Zooming working perfectly fine but issue is my field's text look quite blurry. On same hand the android app's field look quite crisp text while zoom in scale go to 3 and 4, they have native functionality for this but in iOS when zoom scale goes to above 1.0 this get blurry inner view. 
I tried and done following attempt.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(nullable UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    self.contentScaleFactor = scale;
    NSString * scaleFactor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",scale];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UpdateScaleOfFieldsOnZooming" object:scaleFactor];

}



- (void)updateScaleOfFieldsOnZooming:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    float scaleFactor = 0.0f;
    if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        scaleFactor = [notification.object floatValue];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {

            if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                    UITextField * textField = (UITextField *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (scaleFactor>1.5 && scaleFactor<2.5) {
                        [textField setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:(scaleFactor*3.5)]];
                    }
                    textField.contentScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
                    [textField setNeedsDisplay];

                    subViewObject.contentView = textField;
            }
        }

}
```

I fired notification on delegate of zooming end and trying to update text font by scale but Its not working good, some time it goes above than text field size and if not goes than looks blurry.
I need perfect solution for this on zooming. Look for help.
Thanks

Comment: Is your text field frame integer values or float values?  If you align the frame to integer values you may get better results.  Otherwise you are asking the OS to interpolate the letter characters on subpixel values and it does the best it can...

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: No not yet for textfield but for UILabel I found some solution to make it crisp.